# Replace the `to_xls` gem to generate 'xlsx' files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, ruby, xlsx

I have a rails application where I am generating the 'xls' files using the `to_xls` gem but now I want to generate 'xlsx' files instead.

So I wanted to ask if is there a way I can generate the 'xlsx' files using the `to_xls` gem only? If not, what other gem should be the best to generate the 'xlsx' files?
(I was thinking maybe `roo` or `axlsx` gem should be right for this.)

I am attaching the code that I am currently using to generate the 'xls' files as I need to update this code only

```
class ToXmlResponder < Dossier::Responder
  def to_xls
    set_content_disposition!
    controller.response_body = to_xls_raw
  end

  def to_xls_raw
    book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new

    xls_content.write_book(book)
    xls_metadata.write_book(book)

    response = StringIO.new
    book.write(response)
    response.string.force_encoding('binary')
  end

  def xls_content
    xls_opts = collection_and_headers(resource.raw_results.arrays)
    headers = xls_opts[1]
    items = resource.results.hashes.map{|h| Hashie::Mash.new(h) }
    columns = resource.raw_results.headers

    ToXls::Writer.new(
      items,
      :columns => columns,
      :headers => headers,
    )
  end

  def xls_metadata
    ToXls::Writer.new(
      [
        {
          :name => I18n.t('report_info.start_date'),
          :value => resource.start_date_in_timezone(resource.user_time_zone).to_s
        },
        {
          :name => I18n.t('report_info.end_date'),
          :value => resource.end_date_in_timezone(resource.user_time_zone).to_s
        },
        {
          :name => I18n.t('report_info.export_by'),
          :value => resource.user.username.to_s
        },
        {
          :name => I18n.t('report_info.export_date'),
          :value => Time.now.in_time_zone(resource.user_time_zone).to_s
        }
      ].reject{|r| r[:value].empty? }.map{|r| Hashie::Mash.new(r) },
      :name => I18n.t('report_info.sheet_name'),
      :columns => %i[name value]
    )
  end
end
```

I would really appreciate it if someone would be kind enough to help me out with this by pointing me in the right direction like where should I even start.
Please help me out here by going through the above code snippet and let me know how do I update it to generate 'xlsx' files instead

Comment: The to_xls gem isnt maintained anymore it looks like (last release 2014). I'd upgrade sooner rather than later. The roo gem is for reading not writing xlsx I believe. The axlsx gem is good but I've been using fast_excel lately for performance

Comment: You just need to pick a xlsx library and rewrite the code. as @Arctodus mentioned `axlsx` or `fast_excel` are both good options. `axlsx` is bit more full featured but given what you are doing here those additional features are likely overkill.